# Changing Rails 3 app's layout based on the hostname/domain for branding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have a single codebase that should dynamically select a layout based on the request, is there a way to do this?  Can I intercept the request at the Application controller level and change layout from there?

This is primarily to avoid deploying the same codebase to 5 different directories.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a Proc for your layout and choose the correct template for the host:

```
  layout Proc.new { |controller| controller.request.host}
```

Obviously, this won't coalesce subdomains to a single layout, but that's left as an exercise for the reader..

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on this answer? Where do you define the layout object?

Comment: For a site-wide layout, you'd put it in your Application controller.